# Is this context-free grammar unambiguous?

Tags: grammar, theory, context-free-grammar

I would like to know if the grammar I came up with is unambiguous.

```
G(N, T, P, S)

N = {S, M}
T = {+, -, (, ), 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
P = {
S → 0, S → 1, … , S → 9
S → ( M )
M → S + S
M → S - S
M → S
}
```

S is the start variable, N is the set of nonterminal characters, T is the set of terminals and P is the set of productions.

Comment: It's not ambiguous, since it requires expressions to be fully parenthesized. However, note that it does not recognise numbers consisting of more than one digit, which might be considered a flaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This grammar is unambiguous, and it is also nondeterministic. A grammar is ambiguous  when there is more then one syntax tree, for at **least one** valid input string, and is deterministic, if for **every** valid input string, at any time during the parsing, there is at exactly one prediction to use. For the invalid input strings, there will be a moment when there will be none predictions to use.

The predictions `M → S + S`, `M → S - S` and `M → S` make the grammar nondeterministic, because `S` is the first nonterminal symbol of each of them. However, this will not lead to more then one syntax tree for any input, after all of the input is parsed, because the terminal symbols after `S` are `+`, `-` (in `M`) and `)` after the nonterminal `M` in `S → ( M )` will unanimously determine which prediction is valid.

This grammar could be written in the ABNF standard syntax like this:

```
S = "0" / "1" / "2" / "3" / "4" / "5" / "6" / "7" / "8" / "9" / "(" M ")"
M = S "+" S / S "-" S / S
```

After left refactoring, the grammar can become a deterministic one (that will not change the ambiguity, i.e. the grammar will still be unambiguous):

```
S = "0" / "1" / "2" / "3" / "4" / "5" / "6" / "7" / "8" / "9" / "(" M ")"
M = S [("+" / "-") S]
```

And with the shorter ABNF range syntax:

```
S = %x30-39 / "(" M ")"
M = S [("+" / "-") S]
```

Or with a one-liner with its automata under it:

```
S = %x30-39 / "(" S [("+" / "-") S] ")"
```

[image]

Comment: The grammar is certainly deterministic. It is just not LL(k). If you fed it into the LR(1) algorithm, a deterministic parser would be produced.

Comment: No, the grammar is nondeterministic, because `M → S + S`, `M → S - S` and `M → S` all start with `S`, that means that all reachable terminal symbols in `S` conflict with each other when used by an LL parser / deterministic pushdown automata.

Comment: Also the grammar is in fact LL(2), because after the first terminal symbol is consumed from `S` in `M` the next symbol of a valid input would be `+`, `-` or `)`, and that makes it LL(2), because two symbols are needed to disambiguate the valid alternative of `M`.

Comment: DPDA and LL parser are not synonyms. Not every DCFL is LL(k)

Comment: `S` can start with an arbitrary number of open parens, so I don't think LL(k) is possible.

Comment: Please read the question and the answer. There is not a discussion of DCFL, but about DCFG. `S` can start with only one scope, I do not know where are you seeing this scope ambiguity.

Comment: Nikolay: `S->(M)->(S)->((M))->((S))` etc. It's not an ambiguity and I don't know what you mean by scope in this context. But it is not LL(k)) afaics.

Comment: @rici: the grammar is LL(2), and you are again wrong, as are nearly all up statements of yours. This start scope is with one repetition, it cannot be skipped (i.e. its not `0*1 "("`). CFG is not the same as CFL, ambiguity is not the same as determinism, and parsing by regular grammars is not the same as the parsing by CFG. Please give another answer to the question, when you think I'm wrong, thank you.

Comment: Maybe I don't get the definition of LL(2) that you're using. I would have thought that LL(2) means that you need to be able to predict which production for `M` to use based on two characters of unconsumed input, which is not possible if the two characters are `((` (or `(` followed by a digit, for that matter). The `)`, `-` or `+` which would determine the prediction might be arbitrarily distant from the input point. But whatever.

Comment: (And obviously if you left-factor the grammar, it's LL(1). That's not in dispute either.)

Comment: I like your effort, but that is not true. With one scope you already predict that the prediction of `S` to use is the one with the scope, the other predictions of `S` are the digits. Any other token to use after that is just another step of the parsing. They do not interfere with each other. That is not the place of the nondeterminism. The place is in `M` as I have written in the answer.

Comment: yes, for `M`. That's what I said."you need to be able to predict which production for **`M`** to use based on two characters of unconsumed input." In a top-down parser, the `M` prediction needs to be made before you predict which production for `S`.

Comment: Ah! True for the LL(k), I give you that - the grammar is not LL(2). I was not paying enough attention to the pseudo recursion, because this was not part of my initial thoughts about the question/answer. But this does not change the answer, its still correct in any aspect.